# nodejs adds session info to url if it detects user forbid the cookies

Tags: node.js, express

As I know, php can add session to url if it detects user forbid the cookies.
Just hope to know if nodejs/express has the similar function.

Your comment welcome

Comment: Not really, you can set up PHP to use trans_sid instead of cookies, where the session is stored in the URL instead of cookies, but it's a really bad practice, and noone does this today, so trying to emulate that with Node is a really bad idea. Your users should enable cookies, or expect to not be remembered.

Comment: bad practice? I can not understand, if user forbid cookies, how to process for the password-protected site?

Comment: You simply tell the user that cookies are required to log in.

Comment: I noticed that yahoo still use the way to encode the session to url